# Setting all text boxes default value when application loaded

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a VBA app built in MS-Word that has a lot of text boxes spread across many userforms that our users can fill out or not fill out.

I'd like to avoid the values being NULL since these values get passed into SQL tables.

Is there a way to globally set the default value of these boxes to " " so that they upload a blank instead of NULL?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, set the value of the textbox.

[image]

OR on the load event you can write a whole bunch of statements that say

```
 Me.TextBox1.Value=""
```

I would also like to add setting the textboxes to empty strings, in my opinion, is a bad option. Account for the nulls the proper way. There's many different ways to handle this. I also dont see the issue with inserting null into a column where nulls are allowed. But I also dont know youre structure so whatever.

Comment: My main issue with null values is that when they are pulled back from the tables by VBA they cause errors. If the column has nothing in it at all it's fine, but if it has NULL in it it causes errors.

Comment: Again there are proper ways to handle nulls for both side of the data traffic.

Comment: can you elaborate on that?

Comment: Well the advice might change based on how youre loading the texboxes with the values form the sql tables. Can you share what youre using to do this? ISNULL() function is pretty useful